# Designing Compilers: Eliminating left recursion, special case

Tags: computer-science, recursion, automata

Eliminating left recursion is a technique in designing compilers, as discussed here

Examples that I have seen were like this:

```
S -> Aa | b
A -> Sb | Ag
```

that is, one expression has just one of the non terminal and also not itself. I know how to solve this kind of left recursion example and I have found several tutorials on this.

What about if in the first expression we also have a non terminal that is the left non terminal, I mean something like the grammar below:

```
A -> Ba | Aa | c
B -> Bb | Ab | d
```

That is, in both expressions we have a recursion to both A and B.

In the first example I provided, we simply substitute "S" with "Aa | b" in the second expression so we will obtain " A -> Aab | bb | Aag | bg " and then we can simply solve it with the rules defined in the tutorial that I have linked above.

But for the second expression, substitution wont work. So in this case, what is the best way to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this is the wrong SE for this question.

Comment: [This](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) may be a better SE for the question, but you may also get answers here.

Comment: One strategy would be to observe that the grammer is left-regular, so write down an NFA for the language it generates and then read a _right_ regular grammar off the automaton.

Comment: @Mark https://cs.stackexchange.com/ would be better than CS Theory. CS Theory is like the MathOverflow analog of the CS StackExchange.

Comment: I am sorry... so what should I have done?